# MS sql 2012 Tuning process exited unexpectedly. DTAEngine

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-tuning

I am using **Windows Server 2012**, **Ms SQL 2012**.

I am running Database tuning advisor and the settings :

1. advisor plan cache.
2. Database workload `master`.
3. Check my database all the tables.

When tool is started after few seconds i ma getting :

**MS sql 2012 Tuning process exited unexpectedly. DTAEngine.**

After some "googling" i found that i should install service pack 1 MS sql server. So i did it.

Same result.

If someone has experienced something like this please advise me.

Thx for your time.

Comment: The solution is here:

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62898/sql-server-2012-tuning-process-exited-unexpectedly-dtaengine/62936?noredirect=1#comment113208_62936

It works fine.